# My while loop isn't working for input validation

Tags: python, validation, if-statement, while-loop

```
end_program = False
while end_program == False:
    user_choice = input('\nWould you like to play a game?\n Please pick yes or no\n').lower()
    if user_choice != 'yes' or 'no':
        print('You didn\'t pick yes or no...try again please\n')
        end_program = False
    else:
        end_program = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
end_program = False
while end_program == False:
    user_choice = input('\nWould you like to play a game?\n Please pick yes or 
    no\n').lower()
    if user_choice != 'yes' or user_choice !='no':
       print('You didn\'t pick yes or no...try again please\n')
       end_program = False
    else:
       end_program = True
```

When checking multiple conditions you need to be specific: 
You can't say:
`if user_choice!= 'yes' or 'no'` 
Having the 'no' here is causing the error. You will need to check if condition individually:

```
if user_choice != 'yes' or user_choice != 'no':
```